# How get an event when text in a TextField changes? JavaFX

Tags: events, javafx, textfield

How can I generate a new event to handle whenever TextField's text is changed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Or Use `ChangeListener` interface.

```
textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
            String oldValue, String newValue) {

        System.out.println(" Text Changed to  " + newValue + ")\n");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is useful! But any idea how I can register the change say when I hit the 'Enter' key?

Comment: Well then put this listener inside the listener for the *Enter*, inside the *Enter* listener's callback to be precise.

Comment: If you want to catch the Enter key, I believe you want `setOnAction`; my understanding is that by default, pressing Enter in a text field "submits" the form by invoking the registered action, if any.

Answer (score 20):

Register a listener with the `TextField`s `textProperty`:

```
textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
    System.out.println("Text changed from "+oldText+" to "+newText);
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

my solution:

```
....
String temp;
....
//previously in some method when starting to take initial value of the textfield and save it in a temporal
temp=id_textfield.getText();
....
//when losing focus we check if the new value is different

id_textfield.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

            //focus in
            if (newValue) {
                temp = id_textfield.getText();
            }

            //focus out
            if (oldValue) {

                if (!(temp.equals(id_textfield.getText()))) {
                    System.out.println("New String")
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: this code work fine. I don't understand the negative